# Should we avoid "gimme the codez" questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, please-do-this-for-me

At Stackoverflow and other coding-related sides, it is kept a best practice to avoid asking and/or answering questions which simply ask to get the code for a particular (often oddly specific) scenario. Should we practice this at TeX.SE?

### Examples

---

Here are some examples:

- [Customizable Timeline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302088/customizable-timeline). This one is better than most others since the original asker has very clearly tried writing a substantial part of the code himself. Maybe we should give credit since ultimately his customizations required TikZ, but he wrote most of the code in another package himself.
- [How to create a timeline without integer numbers for events?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272541/how-to-create-a-timeline-without-integer-number-for-events?rq=1) This one is worse since it doesn't really demonstrate whether the asker has put any effort at all into the question. The asker also asks for specific requirements in the accepted answer's comments which the answerer has to edit his question to fit. Granted they are not substantial but still.
- [Turn off caption prefix WITHOUT using caption package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301742/turn-off-caption-prefix-without-using-caption-package). This is one of my own. Yes, I'm guilty of this myself. I didn't write any code to even *try* to figure it out, I just asked. As you can see this question's comments pan out similarly to the comments in the one above, with me continuously demanding requirements from `egreg` (the answerer) to fit my specific needs. I didn't need to put any effort into it except copy-pasting his code into my document. And this time, the edits to fit the requirements are substantial and require (a lot of) thought.

I'm sure there are plenty more.

So, what do you think about this? If you agree that such questions should be discouraged, why? How exactly should we word it and implement it? If you disagree, why?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Why are poor questions still upvoted and answered?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6305/32888), [Consistent policy about downvoting and asking the OP to 'show what they have tried'](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2879/32888), [“Draw this for me” etiquette](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4591/32888), [Do we need a new closing reason for “do it for me” questions?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6229/32888), and [Our Do-it-for-me and Draw-it-for-me comments don't reflect our hypocrisy. Can they be improved?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4267/32888)

Comment: There might be more. That's what I found with just a quick search. This seems to come up in some form or another every so often on meta.

Comment: For the caption "just ask" type question, I tend to do this in the chat room. I figure there must be a quick solution that would take me a long time to search out, and often there is. But not always--then I make a MWE and post a real question.

Comment: @AdamLiter Has there been ANY conclusion regarding these?

Comment: Yes. We don't do anything about them other than discouraging them.

Comment: @AndrewCashner But new users do not have access to chat, so they don't have this option.

Comment: Such questions are discouraged, yet they still receive answers.  Actually, answers to do-it-for-me questions are among my highest rated answers ([1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/291627/10995), [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168297/10995), [3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165895/10995).  Note that in [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/291627/10995) the MWE was added after I answered.).  These questions have a ridiculous amount of upvotes whereas they would have been downvoted to hell on other SX sites.

Comment: Furthermore, this issue is discussed very often on Meta and your particular question does not really add value to discussion and I consider it therefore duplicate of [“Draw this for me” etiquette](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4591/10995).